# Update batch using checkbox, failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to update the data using array and checkbox. If the checkbox checked, status become "1". Else, leave it "0".

I have try something like this

```
<?php
  foreach($report as $r){;
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="1" value="<?php echo $r->status;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_name[]" value="<?php echo $r->id_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $r->name;?>">

<?php } ?>
```

and this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="id_name[]" value="<?php echo $r->id_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $r->name;?>">
```

But both of them update the first row even I check the third or the fourth row.

my controller is something like this

```
function update_approval() {
            $status = $this->input->post('status');
            $id_name = $this->input->post('id_name');
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
    for($a=0; $a< sizeof ($id_name); $a++) {
                    $data[$a] = array(
                        'status'    => $status[$a],
                        'id_name'   => $id_name[$a],
                        'name'      => $name[$a]
                        );
            }
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_m_name', $data, 'id_name');
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. Thanks,

I change the position, here is my views

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id_name[]" value="<?php echo $r->id_name;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $r->name;?>">
```

and here is my controller

```
function update_approval() {
            $id_name = $this->input->post('id_name');
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $data[$a] = array();
    for($a=0; $a< sizeof ($id_name); $a++) {
         $data[] = array(
             'status'    => 1,
             'id_name'   => $id_name[$a],
             'name'      => $name[$a]
             );
         }
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_m_name', $data, 'id_name');
}
```

so if I check the box, it will post the id_name that I choose

Answer (score 0):

thanks, but I had tried yours, I get undefinied variable `$a`. So, I changed the position and removed `$data[$a]= array();` . Below is my code (after resolve my problem) based on yours:

```
function update_approval() {
    $id_name = $this->input->post('id_name');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');

    for($a=0; $a< sizeof ($id_name); $a++) {
        $data[$a] = array(
            'status'    => 1,
            'id_name'   => $id_name[$a],
            'name'      => $name[$a]
        );
    }
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_m_name', $data, 'id_name');
}
```